# How to use BlockingCollection for image caching

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm hoping someone may please be able to assist me with a programming solution.  I currently have a machine that acquires a bitmap image of an item on a conveyor.  An image is acquired from the camera about every 5 seconds.  I need to store (cache in memory) the most recent 4 images or so.  Almost like a stack, where each time a new image is acquired, I need it at the top of the stack and it pushes the others down such that the last (oldest) image is dropped off.  I was thinking of using a collection for storing these bitmaps.  When I add the bitmap I will also add the unique "key" identifying the image.  Since things need to run concurrently on this machine, I was thinking of using a BlockingCollection such that they run on their own thread using the producer-consumer method (from what I have researched).  However, I have no experience with this and no idea how to get started.

After these images are taken and cached into my collection, the item moves down the conveyor a little more and then another image is taken of the same part with a different camera.  An inspection is performed on this second image and if it is determined a "fail", I need to save this second image out to disk AND save the previous image of that same part (from the first camera).  This is why I need to cache them and be able to retrieve them.

NOTE: The cameras are NOT next to one another such that the second image is acquired immediately after the first.  Up to 2 or 3 parts may have gone past the first camera before they reach the second camera (as they go through a process in-between).

My idea is to
1). In my GUI thread I want to create an instance of a collection class to store the bitmap images and along with their unique keys.  When an item is added to the collection the add method will determine the collection count and automatically remove the oldest one.

2). At certain instances (a "fail" at the second camera as described above) I will need to check/grab an image from the collection.  I would like to use the TryTake method so that it will obtain the bitmap (based on the key that I provide) from the collection.  I don't want the grabbing of the image from the collection to interfere with the possibly of adding one at the exact same moment.

3). Lastly, once I've obtained the image from the collection, I need to save that image out to disk along with the second image.  I would like the save process to run on its own thread as well so that it doesn't impact performance or the ability of the app to need to work with the collection during a save process.

I have no idea how to get started on this except to make a class called cImageCache and add a property for the unique key.  Any coding examples/help in either C# or VB.NET would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you very much for your time.

Kindest Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO! We are not going to code this up for you. I would suggest that you make a prototype and re-post any questions that you have, but you first need to take a stab at it. Additionally, you do not need to put a greet or signature in the question.

Comment: Thank you Ryan.  I'm working at it and going to try to work on this on my spare time over the weekend.  I have found this forum very useful many times and believe it's not out of line to at least be provided with some sample code, stepping stones if you will, to get started.  Not asking to have it written, but how to use the BlockingCollection, storing the bitmaps, using TryTake, etc. in similar example(s) which will most definitely help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an [ObjectCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.objectcache).  Come up with a key for the item, and store it.  You can set it to be removed from the cache after a certain amount of time.  It is threadsafe.